# Angular 8 - How to use pipes in an input with 2-way data-binding?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe, angular8

I'm a relative newbie when it comes to Angular and I'm building an Angular app and am looking to format an input field where a user inputs their income and it needs to be formatted so that it both has a GBP symbol before it and with commas separating out the value into thousands.

So, for example, a user adds their income as *34000* and it will be displayed as **£34,000**

I'm trying to use pipes to help me achieve this and I've tried using the CurrencyPipe and regular Pipes and I get the same issues with both. So, for example, with the number pipe I'll have:

```
<input type="number" (change)="getApp1income()" (keyup)="getApp1income()" [(ngModel)]="app1income | number" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" min="0" step="500" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="500" />
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 14 in [app1income | number=$event]
```

I'll get the same error when using CurrencyPipe as well. I think this has to do with the fact with the fact that ngModel is using 2-way data-binding as I'm using the value entered elsewhere. But I can't seem to find a solution at all and I've looked at various similar issues both on here and elsewhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use a third-party library for this, you can use [**`ng2-currency-mask`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask)

1. `npm install ng2-currency-mask --save`
2. Add `CurrencyMaskModule` to the `imports` Array of the Module that you want to use this in.
3. Use it like this: `<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value" [options]="{ prefix: '£ ', thousands: ',', precision: 0 }"/>`

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-currency-mask-sample?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: ng2-currency-mask is not being maintained

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ngx-mask:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask 
It's quite simple to use and it has many examples on its page:
https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page/main

In your case it would be:
`<input type='text' prefix="£" mask="comma_separator.2" >`
 Then parse to number type in your code

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try @SiddAjmera's solution a try first, but will look at this if that doesn't work.

Comment: His answer is more specific to your problem so if you don't expect to mask anything else, then his solution is probably better, however ngx-mask offers more tools for other scenarios like custom mask pipes so I would check it out anyway.

Comment: thank you! I think his solution is best as I'm not expecting to mask anything else, but I will bear your solution in mind should that change. Thanks again!

Comment: I switched from ng2-currency-mask to ngx-mask last year because the currency mask wasn't working properly for me. I really like the ngx-mask library, and it works with 2-way ngModel binding.